# Expectation of a stochastic integral

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $M$ be a right-continuous local martingale, $s,t$ two times (stopping times, if you like). Under what conditions does the following hold:

$$E\left(\int_s^t X \, dM\mid\mathcal{F}_s\right)\le 0$$

My guess is:

It holds whenever: $E(\int_s^t X \, dM\mid\mathcal{F}_s)> -\infty$

But I have no idea where to start...

[This is no homework]

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a martingale and $X$ is properly integrable, then

$$I_t := \int_s^t X(r) \, dM_r, \qquad t \geq s$$

defines a martingale and, consequently,

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^t X(r) \, dM_r \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) = \mathbb{E}(I_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = I_s =0$$

for any $t \geq s$. Now, if $M$ is a local martingale and $X$ locally integrable, then there exists a sequence of stopping times $(\tau_n)_n$ such that

$$I_{t}^{\tau_n} := \int_s^{t \wedge \tau_n} X(r) \, dM_r$$

is a martingale. Thus,

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^{t \wedge \tau_n} X(r) \, dM_r \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) = 0.$$

As $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_t^{\tau_n} = I_t$, this leaves us with the question whether we may apply some "Fatou-like" argumentation, i.e. whether

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^{t} X(r) \, dM_r \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_s^{t \wedge \tau_n} X(r) \, dM_r \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) = 0.$$

Obviously, this works out if the dominated convergence theorem is applicable; that is

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \int_s^{t \wedge \tau_n} X(r) \, dM_r \right| \in L^1(\mathbb{P}).$$

---

Note that we can in general **not** expect that the stated inequality holds without further assumptions on $X$ or $M$. Consider for example $X=1$, then

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_s^t X \, dM \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right) \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \leq M_s$$

i.e. the inequality holds if $M$ is a supermartingale.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into your answer... Do have a reference for the very first statement? (That the stochastic integral is a martingal for martingale integrators?)

Comment: @user4514 I think this fact is proved in every book which introduces stochastic integration which respect to (semi)martingales, e.g. Ikeda/Watanabe (Stochastic Differential Equations and Diffusion Processes), Protter (Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations) or -if you are looking for a more gentle introduction- Schilling/Partzsch (Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes.)

Comment: I only find statements about the preservation of the *local* martingale property, none about martingale property (for unbounded processes).

Comment: @user4514 What's an "unbounded process"? In order to define the stochastic integral you need some condition on the integrability of the (local) martingale; namely that it is a local $L^2$-martingale.  Depending on the integrability of $X$ you get a local martingale or a martingale. See e.g. Ikeda/Watanabe, pp.55-57.

Comment: @saz did you mean $\liminf$?

Comment: @dafinguzman Which one? The "Fatou"-like estimate? No, there it is enough to have the upper bound with $\limsup$ (with "Fatou"-like I meant that we (would like to) get an upper bound by pulling out the $\limsup$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\limsup \dots) \leq \limsup \mathbb{E}(\ldots)$.)